# Change Width of Select of Listbox

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-foundation

I am using a select (source from other list) in my form, but the width is too small to show entire options.
How to change this width?some idea?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could override the default CSS.

Sample demo:

Use developer tool to check the element attribute.
[image]

Insert script editor webpart into the list form page and insert the CSS to overwrite default CSS.

```
<style>
select[title="MultiLookup possible values"]{
width:260px !important
}
</style>
```

[image]